# Trigger some JavaScript function with selenium on a webpage to load new elements

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to get some data from a webpage:

https://www.cabotcorp.com/solutions#product-index

On this webpage, whenever you scroll down to the end, it takes a couple of seconds and then loads a new set of items.

When that happens something gets added to the HTML which I want to look at with selenium in python.

So my question is pretty general:

Is there a way to force the function that loads the new elements?

My first idea is as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "some class at the bottom of the page"))
```

This is the code I would use to let selenium scroll down to some element on the webpage. After that I would just sleep for a set amount of time to assure that the new elements loaded in.

However, I noticed that this webpage uses "ddscrollspy"

https://github.com/dynamicdriverepo/ddscrollspy

Is there a way to use selenium to trigger a new set of items?
I'm basically looking for a function that triggers certain Javascripts that are available on a certain webpage.

Edit:

A friend suggested looking for triggers:

This is what I found in Chrome:

[image]

So I now have access to the code that gets executed whenever something new loads. Now I just need to know how to trigger that code on demand.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Every time you scroll down it send a request on - `https://www.cabotcorp.com/-/item/v1/productSearch?q=*&page=1&size=25&mode=productindex` url. Change the page number in the url and you will get you a response in JSON. process it and retrive your data.

Comment: That's pretty smart. It helps a lot. Thank you.